# What happens when an Interface is implemented more than once with the same method signature but for different results?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

*I know the question sounds awkward but I could not think of how to articulate it.

I am looking at project that is using Castle Windsor IoC when I run across the following scenario.

```
public class ParentClass
{
    private readonly ICommonInterface _commonInterface;
    public ParentClass(ICommonInterface commonInterface)
    {
        this._commonInterface = commonInterface;
    }
}
```

Now this is obviously not remarkable, but when I looked to see what was implementing this interface I found the following:

```
public interface ICommonInterface
{
    void DoWork();
}
```

---

```
public class Class1 : ICommonInterface
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
       //Do x;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Class2 : ICommonInterface
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
        //Do y;
    }
}
```

Should both of these methods be called? Is there something here I should be seeing but not? When I've tried to replicate this using .NetCore's built in container only `y` is performed.

Comment: Though I do not fully understand your question, you probably need to go read about `Interfaces` in general and how they work in OOP languages. The problem you are trying to explain is exactly what Interfaces are meant for and without going into specifics, you would want to have interface when you can have multiple `implementations`, again not the sole purpose of having interfaces in any way. With DI frameworks you sort of want that to happen to make you code unit testable as an example. You can have `Class1` as your original implementation whereas `Class2` as your `test` class for example

Comment: Those are instance methods, so that only means that the work that `Class1` does is different than `Class2`. The interface only defines a contract, so that you can pass either of those types to a method that expects an `ICommonInterface` type, and that method knows that it can call `DoWork` on the object passed to it.

Comment: You are seeing only `y` performed in your scenario because you would have registered `Class2` as the 'implementation' class for the interface `ICommonInterface`

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, an interface is a contract to implement certain methods in a specific way. The benefit is that the compiler can verify that a contract which your code relies upon is actually met.

In your specific example, ICommonInterface is being implemented in two different classes and it can be implemented different way. It's upto the caller that which one they want to call.

Comment: Thanks! I had not thought to look and see what class was registered. Only "Class2" is registered in the Windsor IoC. After replicating the scenario with .NetCore I found that the last class registered is what sticks.

Answer (score -1):

When there's multiple classes implementing the same interface, various DI Containers handle that situation in each their own way.

- Some use the first registration
- Some use the last registration
- Some throw an exception because the service is ambiguous
- Some use a special registration somehow labelled as the 'default' registration

There could be other strategies for handling that scenario as well (for example, Windsor natively understands Decorators and Composites), but I believe that these are the main behaviours.

You'll need to investigate what your DI Container of choice does in that situation, or you could save yourself the trouble and use [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di) instead.